# Android GridView scrolls to top on item click

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I have a GridView on Android I populate with custom images. When the user clicks on an image, it goes to a different activity. This works perfectly.

The only thing I would like to fix is that whenever the user makes the selection, the GridView scrolls back to top. I would like to stay on the same position, so when the user goes back to the activity with the GridView, it shows the last scroll position.

Is it possible?

I tried putting a listener on scroll events, but obviously, last captured event is a scroll to the top so I can't use that to move back the scroll where it's supposed to be.

Thanks in advance!

Update: forgot to mention a very important point. I am stuck with API 7. So I don't have `smoothScrollToPosition`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
private int _savedGridPosition = 0;
private GridView _gridView;

...

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("grid_position", _gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("grid_position")) {
        _savedGridPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("grid_position");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    _gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(_savedGridPosition);
}

@Override void onPause() {
    // set in onPause() too since onRestoreInstanceState() is only
    // called when the Activity is destroyed and recreated.
    _savedGridPosition = _gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I forgot to mention it on the question, but I can't use `smoothScrollToPosition` since I am stuck with API 7 in my application... :(

Comment: You're stuck with `setSelection()` then.

Comment: Will try with `setSelection`. Thanks!

Comment: It worked with setSelection after I realized that I had to differ the call with GridView's `post`, since `setSelection` wasn't working if invoked before GridView populated all its elements. Thanks for the help. Will accept your up voted answer.